# In NSIS, how to apply a onClick event on a dialog control at runtime?

Tags: user-interface, dialog, controls, custom-controls, nsis

On this control,

```
 CONTROL "link", 1002, STATIC, SS_LEFT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP, 5, 195, 45, 10
```

In nsis,

```
!define MUI_UI "myUi.exe"
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW LicenseShow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "License.rtf"
...
Function LicenseShow
  ...

  ; Inner window
  FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT

  ; Link
  GetDlgItem $1 $0 1002
  SetCtlColors $1 0x0000FF 0xFFFFFF ; This works
  ${NSD_SetText} $1 "Link to google" ; This works too
  ${NSD_OnClick} $1 on_click_link ; This does NOT work

  ...
FunctionEnd
```

Then,

```
Function on_click_link
    ExecShell "open" "http://www.google.com"
FunctionEnd
```

How can I add a **onClick event** on this 'Label' at runtime ?
I don't want to use **nsDialogs::Create 1018** et **nsDialogs::Show** for this.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSD_On* callbacks only work for controls on a nsDialogs page, try the [ButtonEvent plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ButtonEvent_plug-in)...

Comment: It works with a button thanks, but I'm looking to use event on a text label. Ideally have a control that acts like a hyperlink.

Comment: Do you know how to remove the border of a button in NSIS ? and how to change the button's text color. SetCtlColors does not work on button from what I tested.

Comment: That is correct, SetCtlColors does not work with buttons. For a label, try http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Linker_plug-in

Comment: The linker only works with its example code. I'm not able to make it work. I get the same issue than here http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=340330

Comment: Ok I was able to use NSD_On* callback when using nsDialogs:Create. Otherwise it is too much painful.